# Why my ggplot show flat line? How can i show the Boxplots for every month in order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

#create boxplot that displays number distribution for each month in the dataset

> plot(Bird.Data$Temp,Bird.Data$BFS,xlab="Temp",ylab="BFS",col="blue",pch="*")
> ggplot(data = Bird.Data, aes(x=as.character(Time.Month_th), y=BFSMonthly)) + geom_boxplot(fill="steelblue") + labs(title="BFS Distribution by Month", x="Month", y="Number")
> summary(Bird.Data$BFS)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gqQU.jpg)

#create boxplot that displays number distribution for each year in the dataset

> ggplot(data = Bird.Data, aes(x=as.character(Time.Year_th), y=BFS)) +geom_boxplot(fill="steelblue") +
> labs(title="BFS Distribution by Year", x="Year", y="Number")
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35ppw.jpg)

**why my Boxplots cannot be shown in order?**

Comment: Perhaps there's only one value per month for the boxplot

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to make it easier for us to help you, it'd be great if you could show how the data looks like. Can you copy the output of `dput(Bird.Data)` and paste it in the question?